# Replacing a vintage 2 prong outlet that has 4 sockets?

Tags: electrical, wiring

In one of my rooms I have a very old 2 prong outlet that has 4 places to plug things in. I want to know where I can find a wiring diagram for these types of outlets?
Any help is greatly appreciated. [image]

Comment: Are you in the US? That is surely an aftermarket device which plugs into a regular receptacle to provide 4 outlets, and not a hardwired device itself. A look at your local big box store or a search online will turn up modern equivalents.

Comment: I’m in the Us...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That appears to be an add-on tap, NOT the actual receptacle installed as part of the home electrical system. If you remove the screw in the middle, the device should come off. It is likely an older version of something like this [6-outlet wall plug adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0009HKEXM), except only 4 receptacles and not grounded. You will likely find an ordinary duplex receptacle underneath, missing only the usual cover plate, which can be easily replaced.

The device you currently have is a bit beat up and is not grounded. I highly recommend:

- If the receptacles underneath are not grounded, replace them with a duplex grounded receptacle. This is easy if they are in a metal box that is grounded, or if there is a ground wire in the cable.
- If it is not possible to install a properly grounded outlet, then installing a GFCI would make a lot of sense, as that provides similar protection (others can elaborate on how GFCI is better, different, etc.) but if you need more than two receptacles (i.e., if you plan to install a new device similar to the old one) then you would need to install the GFCI upstream (e.g., at an earlier location, possibly in the breaker panel by replacing the existing circuit breaker).
- If you want to install a new device to replace the existing device, make sure it is UL-listed.

Comment: Would it be safe to unscrew with the electricity on??

Comment: If you have not had any other problems then an addon device like this can be attached & detached safely with the electricity on. But if you (a) have trouble getting the screw in the middle out or (b) have had any problems with any of those outlets - e.g., loose connections, sparks, burning, etc. then I would turn off the fuse/circuit breaker first to play it safe. If you end up replacing the outlets underneath then you **definitely** want to cut power before doing that.

Comment: What if I unscrew and there is no outlet underneath? What are the odds of this??

Comment: Pretty slim odds. But anything is possible...

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Took the dang thing off and everything seems safe again!!

Comment: You're welcome. Real thanks is by accepting the answer (check mark). If you haven't done so already take the tour https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Good answer + I hope OP gives a up vote, so many times we help out and the question stays open because of no up vote.

Comment: @EdBeal - I see the same items come back over & over as "Community" because they were never marked as Accepted.

Comment: Yes I almost want to recommend deleting old questions that were not accepted but that would not be fair to all the folks that did get upvotes from peers and sometimes some really great answers that others can learn from. Maybe recommend the system won't let folks ask any more questions until earlier ones are upvoted or answered by the op and upvoted.